# How to derive the Peak performance in GFlop/s of Intel Xeon E5-2690?

Tags: performance, cpu, cpu-speed

I was able to find the theoretical DP peak performance 371 GFlop/s for the Xeon E5-2690 in this [Processor Comparison](http://sites.amd.com/us/Documents/49747D_HPC_Processor_Comparison_v3_July2012.pdf) (interesting that it is easier to find this information in Intel's competitor than Intel support pages itself). However, when I try to derive that peak performance my derivation doesn't match:

1. The frequency (in Turbo mode) for each core of the Xeon E5-2690 = 3.8Ghz
2. The processor can do an `add` and `mul` operation per cycle so we get: 3.8 x 2 = 7.6
3. Given it has AVX support it can do 4 double operations per cycle: 7.6 x 4 = 30.4
4. Finally, it has 8 cores, therefore we get: 8 x 30.4 = 243.2

Thus, the peak performance in Gflop/s would be 243.2 GFlop/s and not 371 GFlop/s?

Comment: Where did you find the Information that this processor can do an ADD and MUL Operation in one cycle? Is this the Fused Multiply Add (FMA) technique?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Turbo Mode` is not used to calculate `Theoretical Peak Performance`, you have to consider something like:

CPU speed = 2.9 GHz

CPU Cores = 8

CPU instruction per cycle = 8 (considering AVX-256 -> 256 bits unit, can hold 8 single precision values) x 2 (add and mul operations like you said) = 16

Putting all together:

2.9x8x16 = 371 GFlops/s

Comment: It is very important then to point out that you calculated the SINGLE precision Theoretical Peak while my calculation is +/- correct for computing the DOUBLE precision Theoretical Peak except the Turbo mode point and using 2.9 Ghz as you mentioned.

Comment: Turbo Mode is not normally applicable when using all CPU cores. With AVX max DP GFLOPS would be 185.5.

Comment: Flops = floating operations per second